# Possible to assign a label to a table in web2py?

Tags: web2py

In web2py, db table Fields can be assigned a label which effectively acts as the field's name to the site's user. Is it possible to assign a label to a table for the same purpose? This would be useful in situations such as when multiple tables are linked in a grid and the table names are exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each table has a `._singular` and a `._plural` attribute, which are used as labels in various contexts (include the grid). By default, `._singular` is set to the table name, capitalized and with underscores replaced with spaces. You can set the two attributes directly via arguments:

```
db.define_table('mytable', singular='My Table', plural='My Tables')
```

or directly:

```
db.mytable._singular = 'My Table'
```

If you don't explicitly set the plural attribute, web2py will use a heuristic to pluralize the singular label (only works for English).